# NameError when I try to add element to array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to add an element of type TVector to the array vec_list but every time I attempt to add a new element I get an error at

```
@vec_list << TVector.new(input[2...input.length])
```

that says "NameError: undefined local variable or method `vec_list'.

I've tried changing the parameters of the substring and I get the same issue every time. I debug from netbeans and the IDE will not show me any values for anything, they just show up as empty slots in the display.

```
require_relative 'TVector'

class Vectorator
  def initialize()
    @vec_list = Array.new()
  end

  def run()
    input = gets.chomp()
    command = input[0]
    while command != "Q"
      if command == "A"
        @vec_list << TVector.new(input[2...input.length])
            puts vec_list[vec_list.length - 1].to_s
      end
    end
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong and what can I do to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've omitted the `@` in the line `puts vec_list[vec_list.length - 1].to_s`. It should be:

```
puts @vec_list[@vec_list.length - 1].to_s
```

Comment: 1. Thank you for fixing my problem 2. Why does it tell me that the error is from the proceeding line?